# Removing unecessary margins and adjusting height with CSS

Tags: html, css

There are two issues that I'm trying to fix, but can't find a solution

The first one is that the space between the li fields is way wider than the 2px than it should be. How do I remove it?

And other is that the a fields are only as high as the text, although the field height is defined to be 50px.

I also have the normalize.css file enabled from GitHub.

Any suggestions?

**HTML**

```
<nav class="nav-box">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="#">YES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">NO</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav-box {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #f2f2f2;
    min-height: 65px;
}
.main-nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
.main-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.main-nav li a {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ee4723;
    padding: 0 18px 0 18px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #fff;
    font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
    border:solid #fff;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    line-height: 54px;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/uve4ew0q/).

Comment: I added a fiddle, but I don't see the first problem. You can solve the second one by setting the links themselves to `display: block`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## For the spacing issue

This is an issue with `inline-block` elements (extra spacing appears between two such elements). One way to solve this is to give the parent element (in this case `<ul>`) `font-size` of 0 and then setting the `font-size` of the `<li>` element explicitly. There are other ways like negative margin but I find `font-size: 0` method to be the most convenient.
You can read about other methods here https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

## For the height issue

While you have given the `inline-block` property to the `<li>` elements, the child `<a>` elements are still inline. Attributes such as `height` and `width` would have no effect on inline elements. Add `display: inline-block` to the `<a>` element as well for the desired effect

Comment: **EDIT** eveything worked after I pressed F5 furiously for like 10 times. :D

Answer (score -1):

You can use negative margins:

```
.main-nav li {

    margin: 0 -2px;

}
.main-nav li a {

    display: inline-block;

}
```

Comment: Margin sizes vary, using comment tags to clear whitespace, having it all inline/minified in the markup, or setting font size to 0 are all better methods